# How to type hint a function that returns a NamedTuple that has been created within the function

Tags: python-3.x, type-hinting, namedtuple

My IDE's (PyCharm) linter indicates that I'm making a mistake with my `return` type-hinting when creating a `namedtuple` within a function. The problem appears to be that I'm saying that I will return type `NamedTuple` when actually I'm returning type `MyNamedTuple`. How can I solve this?

Example:

```py
from typing import Dict, NamedTuple

def foo(bar: Dict) -> NamedTuple:
    MyNamedTuple = NamedTuple("MyNamedTuple", [(k, int) for k in bar.keys()])
    d = {k: v for k, v in bar.items()}
    return MyNamedTuple(**d)

>>> foo({"a": 1, "b": 2})
MyNamedTuple(a=1, b=2)
```

Comment: You can do `def foo(bar: Dict) -> 'MyNamedTuple'` as a workaround.

Comment: I would say just don't do it, creating a named tuple with essentially any field looks like a very bad practice to me.

Comment: Thanks @Asocia! That could work as a workaround. And thanks for raising @Hollay-Horváth Zsombor - I've just posted separately for a discussion on that [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62301911/is-there-a-dictionary-like-object-that-is-immutable?), in case you'd be happy to take a look. Thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

I believe the problem stems from a slight misunderstanding: the official documentation states that `NamedTuple` is the "Typed version of `namedtuple`". This is not to say that `NamedTuple` is to be used as a type hint itself.

The return type of `foo` as you defined it is in fact `MyNamedTuple`. To break it down, line by line:

1. Define a *type* (i.e., a class) called `MyNamedTuple` with fields  derived from `bar`'s keys.
2. Copy `bar` into `d` (this line is redundant)
3. Return an *instance* of the type created in (1), `MyNamedTuple`

As suggested in the comments to your question, the solution is to set the hint annotation to `"MyNamedTuple"`:

```
def foo(bar: Dict) -> "MyNamedTuple":
    MyNamedTuple = NamedTuple("MyNamedTuple", [(k, int) for k in bar.keys()])
    # d = {k: v for k, v in bar.items()}
    return MyNamedTuple(**bar)
```