# Is there a dictionary-like object that is immutable?

Tags: python, collections, namedtuple

I would like a Python object that can flexibly take any key and I can access by key, like a dictionary, but is immutable. One option could be to flexibly generate a `namedtuple` but is it bad practice to do this? In the example below a linter would not expect `nt` to have attribute `a` for example.

Example:

```py
from collections import namedtuple

def foo(bar):
    MyNamedTuple = namedtuple("MyNamedTuple", [k for k in bar.keys()])
    d = {k: v for k, v in bar.items()}
    return MyNamedTuple(**d)

>>> nt = foo({"a": 1, "b": 2})
```

Comment: **Tragic this was closed.** The [accepted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62302041/2809027) by @torxed presents a superior answer to anything available at ["What would a 'frozen dict' be?"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2703599/what-would-a-frozen-dict-be). Notably, @torxed's `autodict` preserves `O(1)` complexity while guaranteeing immutability by trivially reducing `__setitem__()` to a noop. It's trivial. So, it works. Meanwhile, everything over at "What would a 'frozen dict' be?" is literal insanity; it's all non-trivial, slow, and busted classes over there. I sigh, StackOverflow.

Comment: One use case for these things is caching the result of function calls that take in options in a dict.  Ex:  `@functools.lru_cache`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I mentioned it in the comments, that I'm not sure why this is needed.
But one could simply override `__setitem__` of a [dictionary class](https://github.com/Torxed/Scripts/blob/master/python/autodict.py). Alltho this might *(most likely)* cause problems down the line. A minimal example of this would be:

```
class autodict(dict):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(autodict, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)

    def __getitem__(self, key):
        val = dict.__getitem__(self, key)
        return val

    def __setitem__(self, key, val):
        pass

x = autodict({'a' : 1, 'b' : 2})
x['c'] = 3
print(x)
```

Which will produce `{'a': 1, 'b': 2}` and thus ignoring the `x['c'] = 3` set.

---

### Some benefits

The speed difference is some where between 40-1000 times faster using dictionary inheritance compared to named tuples. *(See below for crude speed tests)*

The `in` operator works on dictionaries, not so well on named tuples when used like this:

```
'a' in nt == False
'a' in x == True
```

You can use key access dictionary style instead of *(for lack of a better term)* JavaScript style

```
x['a'] == nt.a
```

Although that's a matter of taste.

You also don't have to be picky about keys, since dictionaries support essentially any key identifier:

```
x[1] = 'a number'
nt = foo({1 : 'a number'})
```

Named tuples will result in `Type names and field names must be valid identifiers: '1'`

---

### Optimizations *(timing the thing)*

Now, this is a crude example, and it would vary a lot depending on the system, the place of the moon in the sky etc.. But as a crude example:

```py
import time
from collections import namedtuple

class autodict(dict):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(autodict, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        #self.update(*args, **kwargs)

    def __getitem__(self, key):
        val = dict.__getitem__(self, key)
        return val

    def __setitem__(self, key, val):
        pass

    def __type__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        return dict

def foo(bar):
    MyNamedTuple = namedtuple("MyNamedTuple", [k for k in bar.keys()])
    d = {k: v for k, v in bar.items()}
    return MyNamedTuple(**d)

start = time.time()
for i in range(1000000):
    nt = foo({'x'+str(i) : i})
end = time.time()
print('Named tuples:', end - start,'seconds.')

start = time.time()
for i in range(1000000):
    x = autodict({'x'+str(i) : i})
end = time.time()
print('Autodict:', end - start,'seconds.')
```

Results in:

```
Named tuples: 59.21987843513489 seconds.
Autodict: 1.4844810962677002 seconds.
```

The dictionary setup is in my book, insanely quicker. Although that most likely has to do with multiple `for` loops in the named tuple setup, and that can probably be easily remedied some how. But for basic understanding this is a big difference. The example obviously doesn't test larger one-time-creations or access times. Just, "what if you use these options to create data-sets over a period of time, how much time would you loose" :)

Bonus: What if you have a large base dictionary, and want to freeze it?

```py
base_dict = {'x'+str(i) : i for i in range(1000000)}

start = time.time()
nt = foo(base_dict)
end = time.time()
print('Named tuples:', end - start,'seconds.')

start = time.time()
x = autodict(base_dict)
end = time.time()
print('Autodict:', end - start,'seconds.')
```

Well, the difference was bigger than I expected.. `x1038.5` times faster.
*(I was using the CPU for other stuff, but I think this is fair game)*

```
Named tuples: 154.0662612915039 seconds.
Autodict: 0.1483476161956787 seconds.
```

Comment: thanks @Torxed! Though what advantages does this have over the `foo` example above?

Comment: @JamieEdgecombe Not many that I can think of, other than you could define [custom metaclass references](https://realpython.com/python-metaclasses/) and fool applications into thinking it's an actual dict and not `<class autodict>` - although kind of pointless in most scenarios.

Comment: @JamieEdgecombe One advantage that I completely overlooked is that you can use this as an actual dict, named tuples to my knowledge can't be accessed with `nt["a"]` for instance. Which, if you're used to working with dictionaries and expect it to behave like one - is pretty nice. But if you don't care and the lookup times aren't important - either way works.

Comment: thanks again @Torxed! Is that really an advantage though in comparison to say calling it like `nt.a`?

Comment: @JamieEdgecombe Define advantage, it's a matter of taste and expectations. If you expect a "frozen dictionary" to behave like a dictionary, it's an advantage. Otherwise it doesn't really matter.

Comment: @JamieEdgecombe I'll keep adding some benefits, another one I just realized is that you can have numerals as keys in dictionaries, named tuples doesn't support this.

Comment: @JamieEdgecombe You're welcome. dicts are also *(ballpark figure)* x40 times faster *(assuming my third grade math is correct)*.

Comment: another advantage for, i guess, many use cases is that you can add a key that is not already present to your `x` but not to `nt`

Comment: The advantage of a frozen dictionary is that you can use it with the @cache decorator, the "go to" way to memoize a function.

Comment: @CampbellHutcheson Cool, I believe that functionality was added after this post was made so people have to have some form of acceptance for that since I can't go back and change comments on individual posts :)

Answer (score 2):

You can make a minimal class using `frozenset()` to store the data and then add a custom `__getitem__()` method.

```
class Idict:
    def __init__(self, d):
        self.d = frozenset(d.items())

    def __getitem__(self, k):
        return [v for _k,v in self.d if _k == k][0]


d = {'a':1, 'b':2}
a = Idict(d)
a['a'] #1
a['h'] = 0 #TypeError: 'Idict' object does not support item assignment
```

Comment: The problem with this is that it achieves immutability at the cost of losing a dictionary's `O(1)` lookup.

Comment: @JohnColeman Yes, it is true. It is not an efficient implementation.

Comment: On the other hand, the only natural use-case I can think of for frozen dictionaries would be for small packets of labeled data, perhaps passed to a `kwargs` in which case asymptotics are not that relevant.